# Wordpress post preview problem while link sharing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very much new in Wordpress. I have just developed my first Wordpress site and facing a issue here.

While I normally shared a post of any site in messenger or anywhere I got the below image

[image]

But If I share a post of my Wordpress site I got different size image

[image]

This thumbnail image is not bigger like before image and beside that this is not an image of that post, this is my site logo image.

How to solve this ?

Anybody Help Please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use post share plugin. Best plugin is [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).

Just install that plugin into wordpress admin panel and after that getting preview of a post perfectly !

For more details go to [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/facebook-sharing-link-is-not-showing-a-thumbnail-of-the-images-within-the-post).